# Background app and user interaction

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have multiple choice questions app I want if the button that it's content is the right answer it's background be green when it pressed and be red if it is not.

but this part of my code dose not work correctly.

```
private void b1_Clik(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{           
    if (b1.Content.ToString() == ans)
    {
        t.Stop();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

        b1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(250, 0, 255, 0));
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        readQ();
    }
}
```

Comment: please explain in what way this code doesn't work..

Comment: (1) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); (2) b1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(250, 0, 255, 0));
(3) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); in line 3 executing I dose not see the effect of line 2 in the button background

Answer (score 0):

This one would work just fine for me. Is it what you want to do ?

```
private void b1_Clik(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{           
    if (b1.Content.ToString().Equals(ans))
    {
        b1.Background = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 255, 0));
    }
    else
    {
        b1.Background = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0));
    }
}
```

I removed the stuff who does not interact with the question.